# Can we use $n\log n$ instead of $n$-th prime?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Denote $\pi(x)$ be the number of primes $\leq x,$ $p(n)$ be the $n$-th prime number. 
We have $\pi(p(n))=n.$

It's well known that 
$$\pi(x)\sim \frac{x}{\log x}
\\p(n)\sim n\log n.$$

Is it always true that if $f(x)$ is a function and

- $f(x)>0, \forall x>0$
- $f(x)$ is a [monotonic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function)
- $f(x)=O(x^r)$ for some $r>0$
- $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)=\infty$

then $$\sum_{p\leq x}f(p)\sim \sum_{t\leq \pi(x)}f(t\log t)$$?

Comment: what is $f?????$

Comment: @Will Jagy $f$ is a function, such as $x,\frac{1}x,\log x,....$

Comment: If $f(p_n) \sim f(n\log n)$ and $\sum f(n\log n)$ diverges then the [Stolz-Cesàro theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) ensures that $\sum_{n=1}^N f(p_n) \sim \sum_{n=1}^N f(n\log n)$.

Comment: I believe this follows from the prime number theorem, along with some partial summation.